# Datastax C# Driver - How to Map UDT Field to Enum?

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

Is there a built-in way to map a Cassandra UDT (user-defined type) to a C# class with an enum using Datastax C# driver?

Example:

```
public enum Options{
   OptionOne,
   OptionTwo,
   OptionThree
}

public class MyClass
{
   public Options Option { get; set; }
}

session.UserDefinedTypes.Define(
   UdtMap.For<MyClass>()
      .Map(a => a.Option, "option")
);
```

http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.1/csharp-driver/reference/21features/mappingUdts.html?scroll=mapping-udts

Comment: Perhaps. But you should show us code as to what u r trying to achieve so that we can help you. Not everybody knows what Cassandra udt is.

Comment: I dont have cassandra, so I dont know. What happens when you try the above code? Does it map? Or you get some exception?